# Detect if a non-Triggered object is not in Trigger Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a non-Triggered object that is onTrigger with other Triggered Objects, I want to call a function when the non-triggered object is not onTrigger with any other objects.

I tried OntriggerExit, but with this way the function is called when the object exit from a triggered object even when it still ontrigger with another one, I hope you've understood what I mean.

Comment: There is a lot of triggered in your question :) it is hard to understand what you are asking can you clarify your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array or other collection which stores Ids or references of the objects that it has collided with and then remove it whenever the collision stops, or even a counter would work.

```
int _triggerCounter = 0;

void Update() 
{
    if (_triggerCounter == 0)
    {
        //do function
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {_triggerCounter++;}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {_triggerCounter--;}
```

I hope it helps.